# Help with a problem about club sets

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be a regular, uncountable Cardinal and let $f:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$. I'm trying to show that $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid f''\alpha\subseteq\alpha\}$ is club in $\kappa$. I can see why it's closed, but I'm having a hard time seeing why it would be unbounded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to assume more properties of the function, like being continuous at limits.

Comment: @William No, that's not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any $\gamma$, define by induction the following sequence: $$\alpha_0=\gamma+1,\quad \alpha_{n+1}=\max\{\alpha_n,\sup f''\alpha_n\}. $$

What can you say about $\alpha=\sup\alpha_n$?